# how to return php json response to ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, cordova

I have a cordova app making ajax request to php. I want to return the json response first, and then continue processing. In Ubuntu terminal, it works. However in the app, it shows 404.

Mobile

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.0.104/ajaxurl',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"test":"data"},
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(error) {
    // here return 404
    }
});
```

PHP

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
echo json_encode($res);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// continue processing
```

I can't find anything online, probably not sure what to search for also. Anyone knows anything?

Comment: See syntax error at double quotation mark `"` at `data: {"test":"data},`

Comment: i think you're missing a double quote in the line `data: {"test":"data"},` line. Your calls to header() in the php code should come before any `echo` statements. I am assuming your php script is sending errors if it is even getting accessed. You could check the _Network_ tab in your browser's developer tools to monitor the server requests and responses.

Comment: sorry, the " is a typo. In Ubuntu terminal, it works. Eg. in terminal, I can  see {"result":"success"}root

Comment: If you use iOS, you should use https.

Comment: For example, you can echo what you need and run rest of the code in separate background process, php has `exec` function for that. You can't get result of xhr until ajax is complete, and it's not complete until server says so.

Comment: platform? probably a whitelist issue